# Having Vim run commands in a particular file on startup

Tags: vim

I think I might have possibly seen some similar questions on here, but I don't really have anything that answers the question, in a way that I understand. I'm somewhat new to using Vim, so I don't really have much understanding of it's true potential (beyond knowing it is almost limitless). Basically, I have some custom syntax that I want to enable when I open a particular file in Vim. For the purposes of making sure that I don't mess up the implementation of the answer, I'll post the commands in here.

```
:syntax region Topic start="{==" end="==}"
:syntax region Symbol start="<" end=">"
:highlight Topic guifg=#abcdef
:highlight Symbol guifg=#fedcba
```

I can probably guess that giving people guidance to have them figure out the exact answer with a short hop or two is optimal, but I am somewhat frustrated at having to run this particular command every single time I start the file in question. If possible, what could I put, and where would I put, a certain series of characters that would result in not having to type these commands every time I open it?

Apologies if this is a dupe, I just haven't found any answers that I have understood as answers.

Comment: I think [How can I add additional syntax highlighting rules in my local vimrc?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4975/51) on the Vi & Vim site should probably answer your question?

Comment: What's the particular file type? And, more importantly, what Vim says for `:set ft?` when you have one such file open?

Comment: What's your criteria? All files of specific type? Only those within a given directory tree? Or with a given name?

Answer (score 0):

I think putting the vim commands inside a function and calling that function via using augroup might work.

Define the function in your `.vimrc` as:

```
function! Syntax_Highlighter()
    syntax region Topic start="{==" end="==}"
    syntax region Symbol start="<" end=">"
    highlight Topic guifg=#abcdef
    highlight Symbol guifg=#fedcba
endfunction
```

And then again in your `.vimrc`, by using augroup command call the above function:

```
augroup highlighter
    au!
    au BufNewFile *.html call Syntax_Highlighter()
augroup END
```

In above snippet, change `*.html` with whichever file extension you want to.

EDIT :

**METHOD 2 :**

If you want to custom map a key combination to perform those commands then rather than using `augroup` you may use `autocmd`.

```
autocmd FileType html map ,l :call Syntax_Highlighter()<cr>
```

This will map the key combination `,` followed by `l` to calling the `Syntax_Highlighter` function **only when the current file is having html extension**.

Here also, replace `html` with the required file extension.

In the first method, the function will be called whenever you open a new file with the appropriate extension. In second method, the function will be called **only** when you pressed the key combination inside the file which has appropriate extension.